# Stata: testing for serial correlation in residuals of fixed effects model (xtqptest on reghdfe)

Tags: autocorrelation, residuals, stata, fixed-effects-model, error-message

I want to test for first order serial correlation in the residuals of this Stata regression model:

`reghdfe dep_var ind_vars, absorb(i.fixeff1 i.fixeff2, savefe) cluster(t) resid`

My attempts yield errors:

1. `xtqptest _reghdfe_resid, lags(1)` yields `_reghdfe_resid: Residuals do not appear to include the fixed effect`, which is based on `ue = c_i + e_it`
2. `xtqptest _reghdfe_resid, lags(1) force` yields `QP not found` and an `r(111)` error

I understand that the `xt...` analysis tools are incompatible with `reghdfe`, so may need to analyse the `_reghdfe_resid` directly: any hints how?